# I am having sudden PHP and MySQL errors when loading my page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, wamp, wampserver

All of a sudden, I'm having these following errors when trying to load my webpage:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/Program Files(x86)/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_gd2.dll' -$1 is not a valid Win32 application
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/Program Files(x86)/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_mbstring.dll' -$1 is not a valid Win32 application
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/Program Files(x86)/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_mysql.dll' -$1 is not a valid Win32 application
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/Program Files(x86)/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_mysqli.dll' -$1 is not a valid Win32 application
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/Program Files(x86)/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_pdo_mysql.dll' -$1 is not a valid Win32 application
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/Program Files(x86)/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_pdo_sqlite.dll' -$1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I've re-installed WebExpress, WAMP, and MySQL separately after re-installing WAMP.

I can't figure out how to solve the problem. There were valid applications before; I don't understand how all of a sudden they're not valid applications.

I found somewhere where someone said to install the 32 bit version of WAMP instead. I did, and I get the same errors, except instead of `$1 is not a valid Win32 application` I get `The specified module could not be found. I checked the folder and everything is there.

Comment: did you try to google it?

Comment: why did you install them separately? WAMP does include php, mysql and apache in its package.. try again! but only with WAMP

Comment: Just to test it out. I originally installed WAMP and WebExpress. I'm not exactly sure how it works, however, the page won't load if WebExpress isn't "running" (the top left start/stop/restart) option has to be running. I'm not sure why WebExpress (using ISS) has to be running, too. I've already re-installed it a few times. I'm going to try again.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages are quite obvious.

You have mixed a 64bit Apache/PHP and 32bit php extension.

Pick a version 32 or 64 and stick to it.

Comment: That might be it in part. I've found the reason. I'll post an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. I'm running WebExpress with IIS and WAMP at the same time. For some reason it's cross referencing to other configuration files. (I.E., IIS is claiming to read WAMP files, but it's not actually reading them; it just says it's trying).

After re-installing everything several times in different ways, I've found I need to turn off IIS (my database is in WAMP, so I opted to use WAMP). I can still code in WebExpress, but I have to make sure the new port is the WAMP Apache Server port rather than the IIS Apache server port.

Note: Switching to 32 bit or 64 bit didn't do anything but slightly change the error message.